# Chart.js noob - Can't get anything to display

Tags: chart.js

I know I'm just missing one little thing but I can't see it.  I can't get anything to display with chart.js, just white screen.  I've tried many variations and still nothing. I'm testing on replit.com and using the most basic example from the Chart.js website (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/).  If I can just get anything to display I can more forward...

Here is the Replit page:  https://replit.com/@FutureX5/Chart-JS-Tests#index.html

Here is the code I'm currently trying:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>



  </head>
  <body>
    Test if anything is here

<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  in the div
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `<script>` for the chart below the canvas element in the body

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    Test if anything is here

<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  in the div
</div>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }
    }
});
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it was something ridiculously simple!